# Wpf MVVM: What exactly needs to be a view?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm new to WPF and MVVM and attempting to write a firmware programmer so I can update stuff via USB and save and upload setting/state data. MVVM seems like it could work for this. I currently have pages and can navigate around the app (although the nav service is in code behind for now) but I'm stuck on how to implement things that aren't in the standard 'customer'/'person' examples.

On a couple of pages, there are subsections that I can see being sub-divided into separate views hosted in the page, and these subsections are used more than once in the app.

For instance, I want to have a TextBlock that displays the connection status and updates based on signposts in the connection process, firmware update, backup, etc. Progress bars with the % are another. Sections that are used to display errors, data or a selection box depending on what happens connecting would be another.

Having a sub-section house 3 completely different outputs all stacked on top of one another and shown based on the situation seems messy. I can see that section being a ViewBox and creating a unique view for each case being a better solution there (and possibly the other examples above).

Or take the 'status display', I can see implementing it as it's own view and the page's view model will use a messenger to pass the current status back to the 'status display' view model. I can also see it all just handled by the page's view model via calls to it's own methods. I can also see potentially using a global model to hold the status strings (maybe an enum?) and the view model can be made to pull the correct string into a 'currentStatus' variable.

What is the proper way to approach this? Keep it all a single page? Subdivide the dynamic/changing parts from the static parts?

Comment: Without reading much details of the question you wrote. MVVM with WPF is for designing desktop applications. View is the xaml UI layer that you will write.

Comment: Thank you Prateek but my question is about whether to sub-divide views. It's obvious a page would be a view, a toolbar would be a view, a form, etc. But I've also seen what appears to be advocating abstracting this much further so a view might be a button or subsection. Just wanted clarity on where the dividing line is in that regard.

Comment: Make those things a 'View' - Which you want to reuse (today or in future) in other parts of the Application and it also encapsulates a feature/functionality. A button can be a View if it does more complex work than just appearing pretty and calling a handler. For later case, use Styles.

Answer (score 1):

OP:

> Obviously the pages themselves are views, but would it be best to have the 'Status:'display TextBlock and it's value, and the Error/selector section be views also?

If you are asking whether the status and error displays should be `UserControl`s then *yes* they can be *"a view"* irrespective of whether the control is using a view model or not.

Incidentally, it is generally better to use `DependencyProperty`s instead of view models in a `UserControl` otherwise you will end up having duplicate properties in both the view (so that `MainWindow` can databind to it) and in your control's view model (purely for the benefit of the user control).

If your `UserControl` uses `DependencyProperty`s then both users of the control and your view can both databind to the same set of properties without duplication.  In this way you will realise that `UserControl`s have no need for a separate VM.

OP:

> ...the page's view model will use a **messenger** to pass the current status back to the 'status display' view model...

Don't do this, this is what data binding is for.

Comment: Thank you MickyD, that's bringing me some clarity knowing I've got to look into UserControls more. But yes, that's pretty much what I was asking, basically, do we want to sub-divide views as much as possible or is it OK to keep a page a complete page (even if there are quite a few moving parts so to speak)? I'll edit my original for clarity.

Comment: @liquidair thanks.  Don’t forget to accept this as the answer if you believe it so.

Comment: You're welcome. Honestly I'm not quite sure yet. Since they've put the question on hold, I've been stuck trying to figure it out. For a question flagged as "primarily opinion based", 2 books on wpf (Programming Wpf & Applications = Code + Markup) and a week of Google searches turn up very little 'opinion' on the subject. If there's a ton of opinions, no one is sharing them, lol.

Comment: @liquidair I wouldn't worry too much about the flag.  I've seen tons of similar questions on SO and it all depends on the alignment of planets sometimes :)   If I've helped in anyway thats all that matters

Comment: Thank you so much, and yes, you did help! I've got to wire up this view model before I can really try to apply the User Controls (there's not too much on Google for these)...I unfortunately picked the hardest page to start with so I'm figuring out connecting to USB, async Tasks, MVVM and this all at once, haha.

Comment: So user controls are clearly the way to go here, but I cannot for the life of my visualize how to get the binding to work. As of right now, I put the errors in their own class `SystemErrors` based on an `ErrorModel` with a name, description and common causes of the error. The ViewModel then simply passes an index number to the `SystemErrors` class, and a method in `SystemErrors` loads the error data into an `ActiveError` property the user control can bind to to display the error data. What does the DP need to be to work (i.e. ActiveError as a type of SystemErrors)?

Comment: Or is there a simpler way since the System Errors class will always use this user control to display errors? Sorry, WPF is just not intuitive; I cannot seem to get the mental picture of why for instance a user control's binding works differently than a page. In the page, I can simply set the data context in XAML and it's easy, but this doesn't work for a uc.

Comment: @liquidair that sounds like an excellent _new question_.  Feel free to post a new question and optionally mention it to me for viewing :)

Comment: Ya, I was kind of thinking that too, lol. Here's the new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59132108/wpf-mvvm-how-to-setup-binding-on-user-controls